# Php mod rewrite condition display showing improper contents

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect

Using mod rewrite i'm cleaning my url from

```
http://example.com/profile?name=username
```

To

```
http://example.com/username
```

By Using Below mod rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

After adding  this all my other pages like

```
http://example.com/unknownprofile?id=47
```

Showing contents of this page

```
http://example.com/profile?name=username
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few typos in your question, but not sure, so if not:

First url used does not contain profile.php, this would actually mean that

```
http://example.com/profile?name=username
```

would get rewrittern to:

```
http://example.com/profile.php?name=profile&name=username
```

Leading to:

```
http://example.com/profile?name=username
```